# Prove $ \lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (x_{0}, y_{0})} f(x, y) = L \implies \lim \limits_{(x,y) \rightarrow (x_{0}, y_{0})}(f(x, y))^{k} = L^{k} $

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

How exactly would I approach this? How similar is it to the method used for functions of one argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I can see two approaches here.

If your $k$ is a positive integer, then it is enough to show that the limit of the product of two functions is the product of the limits. The approach is the same as for one variable.

If your $k$ is any real number (I guess if you want to allow for negative you require $L \neq 0$), you need to show that the function $G_k(x)=x^k$ is continuous on the real line. Then it follows that the composition $G_k \circ f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2$, from which the result follows. Hope it helped.